# How do I call a node application from a CloudFoundry buildpack?

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I've created my own buildpack and now I need in the release to call to a node.js 
application similar to the command in the `manifest.yml` where you are invoking the node application (command: node app). How I can do the same in the release/compile of the build pack?

In the compile I call to the node.js buildpack and afterwards, I want to run the node application (I Put it in the resources...)

Comment: Are you asking how to call a NodeJS application as part of the buildpack execution or execute the user's NodeJS application from your buildpack?

Comment: @JamesThomas- Yes James I want to call a NodeJS application as part of the build-pack execution,lets say some additional application like server which need to deployed with the application itself to the container

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [multi-buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to install the NodeJS buildpack first before your custom buildpack. You should be able to run NodeJS applications after that.

Comment: THanks James but what I need is that in my buildpack which call to the node js BP and then call to my node app...